# Is there a way to improve my grammar without so much cost?

Tags: language, grammar, learning

### I'm definitely poor at English and I always have grammatical errors.

After posting a question about what apps can I use to start writing my stories, I searched in this site if how can I improve my grammar, and I came across to this [link](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/2954/do-you-have-to-be-good-at-grammar-to-get-published).

English is not really my first language, but I'm desperate to write an English story. But the only problem is, I'm not really so good at English, but that doesn't mean I gave up on my goal. I still want to write an English science-fiction book, but I'm having issues with my grammar.

**Is there something you can recommend me of how can I improve my grammar? Especially that I'm prone to grammatical errors, I still want to find something that can help me without so much cost. You can even recommend to me if there's a software or app that I can use? Thank you for the help.**

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on English Language Learners

Comment: Read a lot. Check out a grammar text book from the library. Read more. Ask a librarian what resources you can check out that might help you. Read even more. The more you read, the more familiar you will become with English, its grammar, and its vocabulary.

Comment: @what Sent to ELL. Unfortunately, we can't add any more options to the system but feel free to vote to close and flag.

Comment: It looks like comments don't carry over when a migration is rejected, so I'll repeat it here: ELL can help if you have specific questions about English, but requests for resources and software recommendations are off-topic. We have a [list of resources for learning English](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/q/735/) that might be helpful. You may also want to check out [softwarerecs.se] to find some language learning software recommendations.

Comment: @Book Striker - Sorry about the back and forth. Have asked for suggestions to focus the question [on chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/35380541#35380541).

Answer (score 1):

I would highly recommend today's high end grammar-checkers (like grammarly which I see 5000 adverts every day for). However, I feel I should make this point:

### Those spell checkers are useless if you don't understand grammar yourself.

You need to understand grammar to make the best use of them. Without an understanding of grammar, they're pretty much useless. They're for checking errors you missed and not for fully fixing incredibly incorrect sentences.

---

You don't need a degree in English grammar to be a writer. Here's what I did. I followed a grammar course online, looked at grammar resources, and identified my own errors. The best way to get good grammar in writing (in my opinion) is the following:

- Get an understanding of grammar. [This was the top search result I got](https://alison.com/courses/English-Grammar)
- Using your new understanding, identify your problem areas.
- Really hammer down on those areas to ensure that in your next piece of work, you don't make the same mistakes.
- When editing, carefully look for **any** grammar mistakes.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly? Just write a lot and have someone ruthlessly criticise your grammar, with explanations of where you went wrong and why. There are a few suitable subs on Reddit where people (like me, who spends a lot of time on /r/fantasywriters) offer critiques for free.

EDIT: Try these..

- [www.reddit.com/r/writers](http://www.reddit.com/r/writers)
- **[www.reddit.com/r/destructivereaders](http://www.reddit.com/r/destructivereaders)  (probably your best bet)**
- [www.reddit.com/r/fantasywriters](http://www.reddit.com/r/fantasywriters) (sci-fi and fantasy overlap so you should be good to post here)
- [www.reddit.com/r/shutupandwrite](http://www.reddit.com/r/shutupandwrite)

Comment: link, please?  preferably not fantasy.  Thank you.

Comment: Edited answer to provide some useful options.

Answer (score 0):

You may try out Scribophile -- a community, where people review the texts of each other (costs USD 9,-- per month).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, there is no magical app or button or program which will fix your grammar. If you want to learn how to write better, in any language, the only solution is to practice, have your mistakes corrected by someone else, and then practice some more. Any computerized solution which fixes your mistakes is only feeding you fish — it's not teaching you how to fish for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

In person would be great if you can find a class, or a person willing to help you.  Do not neglect to consider *auditing* a class.  This is much cheaper than enrolling.

A community college Writing Center would a great place to hang out and get help.

At the university in my town, there is a program for matching people up in language pairing.  For example, if you speak Farsi, you can help someone learning Farsi to practice, and that person would help you with your English.  If there is no program like this where you live, you can put up notices on bulletin boards, especially the public library.

Do not neglect the option of free or low-cost English classes for English as a Second Language.

You could try your local Literacy Volunteers organization as well.

if you want remote interaction, English Language Learners StackExchange is the place for you.